# Opening safari in iphone app using HTTP post

Tags: iphone, http, post, safari

I'm trying to open the Safari browser in my app using http post.

I know how to do this using get, but I can't find anything for http post.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use HTTP post method in your application, I would recommend ASIHTTPRequest classes from http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since in your app you say that you open an app and url goes as an argument. Unless you find out how to pass request method as an app opening argument - you're out of luck.